# C++: Array within Tuple within Vector gets replaced with last entered

Tags: c++, arrays, stdvector, stdtuple

Here is a Minimal Reproducible Example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;


int main() {

    vector<tuple<char *, int, int>> test;
    cout << "During Loop:" << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        char letters[3];
        int firstNumber = i;
        int secondNumber = 4 - i;
        switch (i) {
        case 0:
            letters[0] = 'a';
            letters[1] = 'b';
            letters[2] = 'c';
            break;
        case 1:
            letters[0] = 'd';
            letters[1] = 'e';
            letters[2] = 'f';
            break;
        case 2:
            letters[0] = 'g';
            letters[1] = 'h';
            letters[2] = 'i';
            break;
        case 3:
            letters[0] = 'j';
            letters[1] = 'k';
            letters[2] = 'l';
            break;
        }
        tuple<char *, int, int> toPlace = make_tuple(letters, firstNumber, secondNumber);
        test.emplace_back(toPlace);
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            cout << get<0>(toPlace)[j];
        }
        cout << " " << firstNumber << " " << secondNumber << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "After Loop: " << endl;

    for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
        for (int l = 0; l < 3; l++) {
            cout << get<0>(test[k])[l];
        }
        cout << " " << get<1>(test[k]) << " " << get<2>(test[k]) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
During Loop:
abc 0 4
def 1 3
ghi 2 2
jkl 3 1

After Loop:
jkl 0 4
jkl 1 3
jkl 2 2
jkl 3 1
```

So why do the arrays within the tuple all become 'jkl', whilst the numbers do not change? (Using a string doesn't have this issue I know I could just use that, but I'm curious as to why this happens, as it also happens if the array is of type int).

I'm assuming it is because when making the tuple, its passing by reference into that make_tuple function and that points to the 'letters' array which get changed each loop. If so how would I rewrite this so an Array value could be stored in the Tuple rather than the pointer each time?

TL;DR:
I tried to store a vector of tuples in which one is an array, by entering the tuples through a loop. During the loop it store the correct char array, and I was expecting the tuple would keep the value of the char array as it was entered. However it ends up replacing each char array with the last one entered, as it is actually a pointer that has been entered.

Comment: You don't create copies of the string. All pointers will point to the same array, which will contain the last thing you set it to.

Comment: And what's worse, because this array is local inside the loop, its life-time will end each iteration of the loop, and you will save a pointer that will become immediately invalid.

Comment: Also using `std::tuple` outside (meta) template programming is hardly ever needed. Better to declare a custom struct of your own.  `struct my_data { std::string name; int value1; int value2; }`. You will end up with better readable code. Another option is to use `std::array<char,3>`

Comment: At the end of each loop `char letters[3];`, and all other variables declares in the loop get destroyed. The tuple ends up with a pointer to a destroyed object, an array. All further references to this pointer results in undefined behavior. C++ simply does not work this way, on a fundamental level.

Comment: a `char*` is a pointer. A pointer is not an array. A `char*` is not a string. Use `std::string`

Comment: In this particular code you probably want to replace `char*` with `std::array<char,3>` - since its not an actual string

Comment: How about `std::vector<std::tuple<const char *, int, int>> test {{"abc", 0, 4}, {"def", 1, 3}, {"ghi", 2, 2}, {"jkl", 3, 1}};`?

Comment: `vector<tuple<char *` -- A C++ programmer who knows to use `std::vector` and `std::tuple` *should* know to **not** use `char *` as a "string" type.  As others mentioned, use `std::string` or `std::array<char, 3>`

Comment: Pointers are not arrays, pointers do not extend the lifetime of the objects they point to, arrays are not assignable, this code will never work. More or less the whole point of `std::string` and `std::vector` is to get sensible semantics for object copying and lifetime, instead of the half baked and confusing semantics of pointers and arrays. This is why you should use them.

Comment: Looking at this code, I think you need one of [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)